# Mostrar hash do modal na URL, Bootstrao, hash modal, php

Tags: php, bootstrap

Tenho esse modal que é chamado por essa barra de navegação, sendo que ele está dentro de uma link dessa barra. Com tabs consigo passar o hash da tab para a barra do navegador. Com modal já tentei de tudo e não consegui. Já usei todas as class dele e não consegui. Alguem pode me ajudar. E esse modal o button dele chama um modal para alteração que tem que aparecer o hash na barra de navegação tambem.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid" id="menu">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Menu</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="cadastro.php">Cadastros</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Caixa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Financeiro</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Agenda</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Relat&oacute;rios</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Configura&ccedil;&atilde;es<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color:black;">
        <li><a data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="ModalCategoria();">Categoria</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalFormPag">Forma de Pagamento</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBanco">Banco</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTiposArquivos">Tipo de Arquivo</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Alterar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sair</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<div>
<div class="modal fade form-inline" id="modalCategoria" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Categoria de S&oacute;cio</h4>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form_categoria" method="post" action="">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nome">Nome</label></br>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteLetras(this);" name="nome" size="40">
                                    </div>&nbsp;

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="valor">Valor</label></br>

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" name="valor" size="10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Salvar</button></div></br></br>


                                            <div class="recebeCategoria"></div>

                                            <div class="recebeCategoria_busca"></div>
                                </form>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="modal fade form-inline" id="modalAltCategoria" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myAltModalLabel">Alterar Categoria de S&oacute;cio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form_alt_categoria" method="post" action=""><center>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="codigo">Codigo</label></br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" size="5" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>&nbsp;

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nome">Nome</label></br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteLetras(this);" name="nome" size="40"/>
                        </div></br></br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="valor">Valor</label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" name="valor" size="10"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Alterar</button>
                        </div></br></br></center>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poste o código para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor

Comment: acho que agora consegui